# Shrink existing Windows partition to extend Linux home one?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, dual-boot, gparted

I have one drive with dual boot. I split it evenly between Windows and Linux Mint, but right now almost never use Windows. I want to keep Windows for gaming/Office, but move some of its disk space from Windows C: drive to Linux /home. Can I do that *safely*? Is it possible it's as easy as [explained here](https://howtoubuntu.org/how-to-resize-partitions-with-the-ubuntu-or-gparted-live-cd)? Does gparted take care of moving things around on Windows drive so that no data is lost?

Comment: See also https://superuser.com/q/821131/992527. As mentioned on the page linked in the question it is always good to create a backup because something might go wrong, e.g. a power loss or a program bug.

Comment: Already done, thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've done this several times on several laptops already, never had any issues. And it is as easy as explained there.

But remember to:

1. Defragment Windows drive,
2. Leave some space free for both systems
3. Do not "move around" partitions. If your Linux partition precedes windows → space will be freed after windows partition → you can allocate new ext4 partition and add mounting point of your prefference *

** you can move around swap partition as far as I know

Comment: Defragmentation should be skipped if the drive is SSD. If you have an HDD, I would also consider fixing the size of the Windows swapfile to 2X installed RAM and rebooting before defragmentation, to reduce future fragmentation. I would also turn off Windows Hibernation ability a la https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-enable-or-disable-hibernate-in-windows-10/ , Otherwise Michal's suggestion is excellent.